# Unable to find svg element for unit-testing of d3 component in React using enzyme and cheerio

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component that renders a div element, d3 in another class is used to append a svg element to the above div element.

While unit-testing with enzyme, the find() method is unable to detect the svg element inside the div. This svg element doesn't have any `id` as it was created through d3. I referred this https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1510 but it didn't help.

I referred to another example which uses cheerio to detect html elements but that didn't work either. https://medium.com/successivetech/unit-testing-react-d3-with-enzyme-and-jest-108735046535

Below is the code from the test file. The first test passes i.e the div element is rendered but the second test fails.

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import MostConvProds from './MostConvProds'; 
import { MockedProvider } from "@apollo/react-testing";
import { getDataAndConfig, getHtml, checkSvg } from './Helper';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const setUp = (props={}) => {
const component = mount(<MockedProvider><MostConvProds {...props}/> 
</MockedProvider>);

return component;
};

describe('The component should render according to props', () => {
    let component;
    beforeEach(() => {
        const props = {

        count:1,
        loading: false,
        products: [{productName: 'a', productId: '1', count:10},
                   {productName: 'b', productId: '2', count:9},
                   {productName: 'c', productId: '3', count:8},
                   {productName: 'd', productId: '4', count:7},
                   {productName: 'e', productId: '5', count:6}
                  ],
    }
    component = setUp(props);
 });


 it('Should render the div without any errors', () => {
    const wrapper = component.find('#mostConvProds');
    expect(wrapper).to.have.length(1);
    // const svg = Icons.IconWrapper(props, children);
    // const wrapper1 = wrapper.find('svg').html();
    //expect(wrapper1.find(<rect> </rect>)).to.have.length(1);
})

it('Should render svg element without any errors', () => {
   const wrapper = component.find('#mostConvProds');
   expect(getHtml(wrapper, "svg")).to.have.length(1); 
   //expect(component.find(`svg[viewBox="0 0 440 
   //150"]`)).to.have.length(1);  //didn't work
})
})
```

The Helper.js file is as follows

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

export const checkSvg = (component) => {
const $ = getHtml(component, 'svg');
const svgHeight = $('svg').attr('height');
const svgWidth = $('svg').attr('width');
return svgHeight == '150' && svgWidth == '440';
}

export const getHtml = (component, tag) => {
const cheerioData = cheerio.load(component.find(tag).html());
return cheerioData;
}
```

The error message

```
Method “html” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

   9 | 
  10 | export const getHtml = (component, tag) => {
> 11 | const cheerioData = cheerio.load(component.find(tag).html());
     |                                                      ^
  12 | return cheerioData;
  13 | }
```

Below is the component that renders the div

```
class d3Component extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    new d3class(this.refs.mostConChart, this.props.products)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div id={'mostConvProds'} className={style.container} 
             ref='mostConChart'> </div>
     )
   }
}
```

the `d3Class` is where all the d3 code is present.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'

const HEIGHT = 150;
const WIDTH = 350;

export default class d3Class {
constructor(element, product) {
    const svg = d3.select(element)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", WIDTH + 90)
        .attr("height", HEIGHT)
        .attr("x",0)
        .attr("y",0)


         ...
         ...
     }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you mounting your component in your test file? Some code seems to be missing

Comment: I have updated the question to show how I mounted the component. Please check.

Comment: ok, the mounting looks fine. can you add the contents of d3class too?

Comment: I have updated, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so following up Will Jenkins' suggestion that the problem with `componentdidMount()` being called after the test. I found a solution using cheerio.

```
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');
```

Inside the `describe()` the below test passes

```
it('Should render svg element without any errors', () => {
        let wrapper = component.find('#mostConvProds');
        const $ = cheerio.load(wrapper.html());
        expect($('svg')).to.have.length(1);
        expect($('rect')).to.have.length(5);
        expect($('text')).to.have.length(10);
  )}
```

The d3 elements will now be detected during the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused the fact that your `svg` is being added to the target element in `componentDidMount`, which happens after your test has already completed. Normally it would be enough to call [`wrapper.update()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) to trigger a re-render, but as your d3 code is modifying the DOM outside the React component world the changes it causes won't be registered by diffing engine.

One way to address this would be to provide a callback to your d3class code to be called after it runs. You can use this to update some state on your parent Component so it will re-render the new content when you call `.update()`

```
export default class d3Class {
    constructor(element, product, onComplete) {
        const bars = rects.enter()

          // snip //

          bars.append("svg:title")
          .text(d => d.productName);

           onComplete && onComplete()
```

From the other end, you would hook it up like this:

```
class d3Component extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
         new d3class(this.refs.mostConChart, this.props.products, ()=>this.setState({isMounted:true}))
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id={'mostConvProds'} className={style.container} 
             ref='mostConChart'> </div>
         )
    }
}
```

Comment: I added `wrapper.update();` just before the `expect(getHtml(wrapper, "svg")).to.have.length(1); `  and I got the same error.  Where should I put `wrapper.update()` exactly ?

Comment: It didn't work, I got the same error. Is there any other way ? I saw that there is a problem with the wrapper.update()  method https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2042